# How to know if user is zooming and in which direction using d3 behavior zoom?

Tags: d3.js, zooming

I'm developing an application which use d3 for charting. x axis is time scale. User can zoom in/out to expand or shrink x axis. Now I want to add some logic in the event handler based on the direction user is zooming. But I don't find an easy way to know if user is doing zoom and in which direction.

Can someone share some experience here?

Answer (score 1):

You want to [add an event handler to the zoom](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Zoom-Behavior#on).

To run a function whenever the zoom changes, you can add an event handler for zoom as follows:

```
zoom.on("zoom", function () {
    var scale = d3.event.scale;
    var translate = d3.event.translate;
    // Do your processing
});
```

If you want to tell the direction of the zoom, you can save the `translate` each time, and compare the current one to the previous.

Answer (score 0):

**Direction of zoom : Zooming in or zooming out**

In version 4 of d3, `ZoomEvent` contains `WheelEvent` as `sourceEvent` property. So to have the direction i'am doing :

```
zoom.on("zoom", () => {
    -1 * Math.sign(d3.event.sourceEvent.deltaY)
});
```

`d3.event.sourceEvent.deltaY` gives nigative values when you zooming in, for me i use negative values when i zoom out that's why i'am multipling by `-1`.

The value of `d3.event.deltaY` works only in `wheelDelta` method of the zoom (see code below) but it gives mes values in v3 when i called it in the handler of `zoom`.

```
d3
.zoom()
.wheelDelta((ev, i, g) => {
     return -d3.event.deltaY * (d3.event.deltaMode ? 120 : 1) / 500;
})
.on('zoom', () => {
        // ...
});
```